# Move some components in a React application to a separate library

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app

I have a basic React application created with `create-react-app`. I didn't explictly configure any tool (webpack, rollup, babel...) apart from what comes preconfigured from `create-react-app`. I have some reusable components that I would like to move to a separate package. The application and the package will coexist in a single monorepo, so I don't have any need to actually *publish* the package.

At first, I thought I could just

- create a separate NPM package containing just these components
- add `react` and `react-dom` as peer dependencies for that package
- `npm link` the components package

and I would be able to import the components easily.

Unfortunately, if I do so, I get an error such as

```
SyntaxError: .../demo-components/src/centered_button.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (14:13):

  12 |     render() {
  13 |         return (
> 14 |             <Grid xs md={4} mdOffset={this.props.offset}>
     |             ^
  15 |                 <Button
  16 |                     variant="contained"
  17 |                     size="large"

Add @babel/preset-react (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-preset-react) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-jsx) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

It is not clear to me what I should add and where. I tried creating a `.babelrc` file in the root of my application with

```json
{
    "presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

but that didn't help. Same thing if I put the same file in the root of the components package.

Notice that there are many guides on the internet about how configure and publish custom react component libraries, but such guides;

- are often stale wrt to tool versions,
- require additional tooling (e.g. Rollup), and
- require a separate compilation step, which is inconvenient for development
- I also run into issues about duplicate versions of React etc.

But actually, I don't want to publish anything, just import stuff from a separate folder, and tell the application compiler to *also* compile these components as if they were part of my application. After all I can use JSX in the main application just fine.

> Is there a way to configure a basic React application to treat an external, local package (linked with `npm link`) as if it was part of the application code and apply the same compiler settings that it is using for the main application?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the React app, not being ejected, was using configuration scripts that are hardcoded in the `react-scripts` package.

I was eventually able to modify the Babel configuration (without needing to eject) using [Craco](https://craco.js.org/docs/configuration/babel/)